# UICollectionView Scroll Freeze with NSData (imageView)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsdata, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I've UICollectionView with UITableView in the same page. I'm using `SDWebImage` with `UITableView` and it is working fine. I'm trying to use `SDWebImage` with `UICollectionView` but couldn't make it. So I have used NSData but it is freezing with it. How I can solve this issue?

UPDATE: Is there a way to use `SDWebImage` with `UICollectionView`?

My code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

ProductsCollectionViewCell *pCell = [_collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

_imgCollection = (UIImageView *)[pCell viewWithTag:100];
_imgCollection.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

pCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
pCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

}
```

My code for table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"productCell";

ProductsTableViewCell *pCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

[pCell.imgProduct sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

is synchronous, which means it will block the thread until it's done. (That's why it's freezing)

I recommend you figure out a way to use `SDWebImage` with your code, if you tell us why that didn't work, we can probably help you with that.

EDIT:

Look at the first example from `SDWebImage`'s [documentation](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), specifically at this line:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Now use it instead of this line of your code:

```
_imgCollection.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And also, get rid of the line where you are downloading the image.

Comment: I didn't know how to link it with the `collectionview` as in the `tableviewcell`.  I need to know the way of writing it

Comment: I edited my answer to help you use `SDWebImage` with `UICollectionView`

Comment: I have used your code and edit it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing contentView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

ProductsCollectionViewCell *pCell = [_collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

_imgCollection = (UIImageView *)[pCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
_imgCollection.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Comment: I have added contentView but it is still freezing.

Comment: I can see you have subclassed collectionviewcell why don't you link image view field in interface builder and access here.

Comment: I think pCell may be nil

Comment: I have tried both of subclass and direct link from the interface builder but it didn't differ.

Comment: Check ur ImageData this may be nil

Comment: Can u give me url link string

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the fact that

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL ...
```

is performing a time consuming operation on the main thread?

Why not try putting the fetch in the background like so?

```
dispatch_async(
         dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          if(cell) { // cell is visible
             cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
          }

    });
});
```

Finally, make sure that

```
[_arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

is indeed a string and that _arrayImage is a string array

Lastly I would consider putting

```
[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]
```

in the background as well as the decoding could be time consuming as well

Comment: I have tried this way and it is not freezing but it won't fill all cell's and in the same moment all images changes continuously.

Comment: Yes some of them remain blank. What I mean by change continuously for example I have 10 image all change in the same cell every 0.5 second very fast.

Comment: The reason might be because as you are scrolling your cell disappears before the image loads. As cells are always reused (in both table and collection views), the async block might still run after the cell has been removed and put the image when it has been dequeued (used again) in a different indexPath. Then, the new block runs on the same cell and you see the rapid change in the image. I have modified the code above to capture the index path and use that to try and place the image in the correct cell. Does this make sense?